# Spring Tool Suit(STS) not being installed in Eclipse Indigo 3.7

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-indigo

I am installing STS in Eclipse Indigo 3.7, using http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.7. I want want to install Core/Spring IDE only.
But I am getting an error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190 (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190)
  Missing requirement: Spring IDE Live Beans Graph 3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190 (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph 3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190 (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph [3.2.0.201212062225-CI-B190]

what should I do to install the same?